# When attempting to create the new client, Mongoid could not find a client configuration for the name: 'default'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, mongoid, mongohq

I added production database as the following:

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
      options:
        consistency: :strong
        max_retries: 1
        retry_interval: 0
```

Depend on the following [docs](https://docs.compose.io/tutorials/rails-4-mongoid-heroku.html).

And I created `MONGOHQ_URL` by the following command:

```
heroku config:add MONGOHQ_URL=mongodb://user:pass@server.mongohq.com:port/db_name
```

But when I open the console by `heroku run rails c`. I got the following:

```
There is a configuration error with the current mongoid.yml.

message:
  No clients configuration provided.
summary:
  Mongoid's configuration requires that you provide details about each client that can be connected to, and requires in the clients config at least 1 default client to exist.
resolution:
  Double check your mongoid.yml to make sure that you have a top-level clients key with at least 1 default client configuration for it. You can regenerate a new mongoid.yml for assistance via `rails g mongoid:config`.

 Example:
   development:
     clients:
       default:
         database: mongoid_dev
         hosts:
           - localhost:27017

Loading production environment (Rails 4.2.4)
```

How can I add production configuration in `mongoid.yml` file to deploy using heroku ?

Comment: There is a possible duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369990/rails-environment-mongoid-connection-issue)

Answer (score 14):

They updated the format of the mongoid.yml file in Mongoid 5. Instead of `sessions` it needs to be `clients`. There are a few other changes too, I know `user` and `password` are now nested under options unlike before. See the [Mongoid docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/mongoid-installation/#configuration) for details.

```
production:
  clients:
    default:
      ...
```